# Transformations preserving the number of distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric, invertible matrix with nonnegative real entries, $\mathbf{1}$ be the all one $n$-dimensional vector, and $\mathrm{diag}(v)$, $v=[v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n]^\top\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$. Consider the following transformation of $A$
$$
g(A,t) := \mathrm{diag}((A+tI)\mathbf{1})^{-1}(A+tI),
$$
where $t$ is a nonnegative real number.
Notice that $g(A,t)$ is a (row) stochastic matrix.

> **My question.**  Assume that $g(A,0)$ has $k$ *distinct* eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$. Then, does $g(A,t)$ have $k$ *distinct* eigenvalues for all (finite) values of $t> 0$?

Comment: 1) Did you forget to take the inverse when defining $\Sigma(t)$? 2) How do you enumerate the eigenvalues? What is $\lambda_1$? Do you merely ask whether teo eigenvalues may become equal?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: yes thanks! I fixed the typo. I enumerate the eigenvalues in an increasing order: $\lambda_1$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $g(A,t)$. Basically, I wonder whether there are no crossings between the eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't think $g(A,t)$ is still symmetric.

Comment: @ChristianRemling yes it is not symmetric (there was a typo). However $g(A,t)$ is similar to a symmetric matrix.